# Oracle APEX 18.2 -> need dynamic action based on list of values to make a field required

Tags: dynamic, apex

When overall_status in list ('Yellow Trend Up'...etc) then overall_description is required for user to enter information

overall_status: 
Select List, Required-Above, Status Values(Red Trend Up, Yellow Trend Up)         Dynamic Action * When Event=Custom, item=overall_status, condition=overall_status=Yellow Trend Up 
True: Action=Show, Affect Elements=overall_description

overall_description: 
Text Field * Appearance=Optional-Above 
Validation=Value Required (YES)

When i run application/page and select Yellow Trend Up a Popup window appears with

- Leave site? Changes you have made may not be saved Leave Cancel

Not sure what True: Action should be selected

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the user to be required to fill in a description field when a certain value from the selection list is selected (like 'Yellow Trend Up' in this example), then a simple way to achieve this is to:

1. Create 'overall_status' as Select List.
2. For 'Page Action on Selection' choose: 'Redirect and Set Value'.
3. Create 'overall_description' as Text Field.
4. For 'Value Required' choose: 'Yes'.
5. In the 'Conditions' section of 'overall_description', choose 'Condition Type': 'Value of Item / Column in Expression 1 = Expression 2'.
6. For Expression 1 enter: 'overall_status'.
7. For Expression 2 enter: 'Yellow Trend Up'.

If you want to show this required description field if any value is selected in your 'overall_status' Select List, then choose 'Value of Item / Column in Expression 1 Is NOT NULL' and Expression 1 as 'overall_status'.